# how to get notified when the system kills my app to free memory?

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-management

I am building an app to process some data. when the process is done it shows a notification. if I click on the notification a while after(meanwhile doing some heavy task) finishing the process it crashes. it is due to android cleaning up memory used by the app. Is there any callback method/way to get notified when android force closes an app?

Comment: There is no way to know when an app is killed. When it has been put in the background 'onPause' and 'onStop' are called. This is when you need to save the your data. If you're performing some calls when the app is in the background you should use a service. But in any case you need to make sure you store the necessary data used by the app when the user opens it by clicking on the notification

Answer (score 1):

> public void onLowMemory ()
>
> This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, and
>   actively running processes should trim their memory usage. While the
>   exact point at which this will be called is not defined, generally it
>   will happen when all background process have been killed. That is,
>   before reaching the point of killing processes hosting service and
>   foreground UI that we would like to avoid killing.
>
> You should implement this method to release any caches or other
>   unnecessary resources you may be holding on to. The system will
>   perform a garbage collection for you after returning from this method.
>
> Preferably, you should implement ComponentCallbacks2.onTrimMemory(int)
>   from ComponentCallbacks2 to incrementally unload your resources based
>   on various levels of memory demands. That API is available for API
>   level 14 and higher, so you should only use this onLowMemory() method
>   as a fallback for older versions, which can be treated the same as
>   ComponentCallbacks2.onTrimMemory(int) with the
>   ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE level.

here is documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onLowMemory()